# Is $(5)$ a prime ideal of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{X^5 +2X +2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer which satisfies the polynomial $X^5 + 2x + 2=0$. Then we have $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{X^5 +2X +2}$. I then want to work out whether $(5)$ is a prime ideal in this ring.

My attempt:
$(5)$ a prime ideal iff $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{(5)}$ is an integral domain. However, we see that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{(5)}$ has only a finite number of elements. Hence if it is an integral domain, it is also a field as finite integral domains are always fields. Thus  in this case $(5)$ is a prime ideal iff it is maximal. but we can quickly verify that it is not in fact maximal, e.g. $(2X, 5)$. We see that $(X^5 +2X +2, 5, 2X)$ is not equal to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and hence $(2X,5)$ is an ideal of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{X^5 + 2X + 2}$

My question is then: (1) does my above proof work? and (2) is there a more elegant or shorter way of solving it if this does indeed work?

Comment: *Hint*: you can check that $X^5+2X+2$ has a root in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$.

Comment: unfortunately your claim that $\langle X^5+2X+2,5,2X\rangle\neq\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not correct; note that: $$1=5+2X(X^4+2)-2(X^5+2X+2).$$ thus in particular $\langle\overline{2X},\overline{5}\rangle$ is not a maximal ideal of your ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, recall an ideal $I$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain.

we observe:
$\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(5)$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{Z_5}[X]}{(X^5+2X+2)}$. This can seen by using that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(X^5 +2X+2)}$.

However, $X^5 + 2X + 2$ has a root, $1$, in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. As $X-1$ has leading term which divides that of $X^5 + 2X + 2$, we therefore find that $X-1$ divides $X^5 +2X +2$. Hence $\frac{\mathbb{Z_5}[X]}{(X^5 +2X+2)}$ is not an integral domain, as we found a non zero polynomial $P$ such that $P(X)(X-1)=0$

(directly solving for this polynomial P gives $P(X) = X^4 + X^3 +X^2 + X + 3$. the final term may cause confusion - but $-3=2 \bmod 5$.)

P.S. I wrote this up after seeing Bernard's hint.

Comment: You have a minor typo in the third sentence of your second paragraph ($X$ instead of $2$ in the quotient).